# Python socket client request echo

Tags: python

I am testing communication with a socket server using a simple script built with Python's select module. It works fine - I get responses from the server - except that *any request I send seems to be echoed in the first line of the response* (see command line example below). The server provider says this isn't him echoing the request - what am I failing to do when sending the request ? (flushing some buffer somewhere ?)

---

select_client.py

```
Prompt=">>>"

def loop(chan, bufsize):
    while True:
        r, w, e = select.select([chan, sys.stdin], [], [])
        if chan in r:
            data=chan.recv(bufsize)
            if len(data)==0:
                continue
            sys.stdout.write(data)
            sys.stdout.write("%s " % Prompt)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        if sys.stdin in r:
            data=sys.stdin.readline()
            if data=="\n":
                break
            chan.send(data)
```

---

sample usage

```
>>> hello
hello <--------- ECHO!
error:no_version_specified
>>> login:1
login:1 <---------- ...!
error:usage:login:1:username?:passwd?
>>> login:1:foo:bar
login:1:foo:bar
>>> error:incorrect_username_or_password
>>>
```

Comment: What does your socket declaration look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems perfectly normal. It is a kind of acknowledgement that the string you sent is okay (even if you've been told there is no echo). In your case, I would simply suggest you delete the first line of your `data` variable.

Comment: That's true for the simple example provided, but in a production environment the OP may want to avoid the overhead of duplicating data on the wire. Depending on what the OP is _actually_ trying to do, your answer may or may not be sufficient.